# Get distinctby in azure cosmos dotnet-v3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to get the distinct records from cosmosdb base on ProductName.

I did the change in my code. However, I am getting error Method ‘DistinctBy’ is not supported cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.28.2

```
var iterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Product>(false, null, options)
                    .Where(p => p.catalog == catalog)
                    .DistinctBy(x => x.ProductName)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime)
                    .ToFeedIterator();



var pageNumber = 0;
do
{
  var Response = await setIterator.ReadNextAsync();
  if (++pageNumber == queryParameters.Page)
   {
//some logic here....
   }
} while (setIterator.HasMoreResults);
```

Just wondering. How to achieve this. I am using .Net 6

Answer (score 1):

DistinctBy is not a supported Linq operator as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-linq-to-sql#SupportedLinqOperators)

The only way to achieve this is to not use Linq and call GetItemQueryIterator()

```
string sql = $"SELECT DISTINCT c.productName FROM p WHERE p.catalog = @catalog ORDER BY p.DateTime";

FeedIterator<Product> resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Product>(
    new QueryDefinition(sql)
    .WithParameter("@catalog", myCatalogValue),
    requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
    {
        PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(myPartitionKey)
     });
```

Somewhat optional here is the partition key value in request options. If this is a large container and the query is run with high concurrency you should have one. Even at small scale it's good practice to have.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for response. In my case my select statement return all product fields. for example productName, ProductCode, Description, Price, Discount etc. But the the query in your example will only return ProductName. any advice

Comment: Sure. Just add the fields you want into your query.